# Web Scrape live chaning data

Tags: javascript, html, web, websocket, screen-scraping

I am pretty new to web scraping. It is pretty easy with static content, but I would like to know if there is a way, to scrape a site like that:
https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/

I need to scrape all the live attacks from that site. But I don't even know how to start.

Comment: You try a scraping library like cheerio?

Comment: I tried beautiful soup. But it doesn't seem to be good for dynamic conent. Does cheerio solve this problem?

Comment: you can scrape by html tags, or ids if the dynamic content sits in the same elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you don't need to **scrape** at all.
But look deep into the mechanics.

This site uses built-in [Browser Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

You just need decode from this source:
`https://threatmap-api.checkpoint.com/ThreatMap/api/feed`

Below is a sample fetch call:

```
fetch("https://threatmap-api.checkpoint.com/ThreatMap/api/feed", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/event-stream",
    "accept-language": "en-US,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"89\", \"Chromium\";v=\"89\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site"
  },
  "referrer": "https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

That's a sample event:
`{"a_c":1,"a_n":"DNS Enforcement Violation","a_t":"exploit","d_co":"SE","d_la":63.8284,"d_lo":20.2597,"d_s":"AC","s_co":"US","s_lo":-73.9712,"s_la":40.7428,"s_s":"NY","t":null}`

Which visually seems to mean:

- Description: *DNS Enforcement Violation*
- Kind: *Exploit*
- Target Country/State: *SE/AC - Lat/Lon: 63.8284, 20.2597*
- Source Country/State: *US/NY - Lat/Lon: 40.7428, -73.9712*

Comment: Thank you very much. That was, what I was searching for :)

Comment: Welcome. Also, don't forget to mark this as answered!